Anonymity of Bounties?
Is there any option, and if not then why, where the person raising a bounty can remain anonymous? That is the name of the person will not be shown if they choose to do so, even if the bounty is on their own question.

"anonymous" Why?

There's no such option.
I suspect the 'real' reason is, well, no one thought it was necessary when the feature was specced out and built.
Practically - if you think of reputation as 'an economy', it adds a certain degree of accountability. People would notice, either that someone was burning through reputation with bounties, or more specifically, say if someone was giving bounties to the same few people. People are sometimes tempted to sock after all. It's an anti reputation-laundering tool.
I'd also note if you thought of bounties as a way to get attention to a post, it's nice to know who might benefit. If you're using it to reward a user for a good answer, it's nice to know who loved your answer enough to give you a chunk of rep.
I can't think of any situation where I'd want to anonymously give a bounty.
